# Can I cast Magic Initiate spells from another class using the Pact Magic feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, warlock

If I have a Warlock who takes magic initiate in cleric and chooses cure wounds as the first level spell, could I use my Warlock spell slots to cast that spell as well as the 1/day casting of cure wounds?

I know that Pact Magic can be used to cast spells using the Spellcasting class feature (PHB 164), so shouldn't you be able to use your Warlock slots to cast the magic initiate spell?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate, as I believe it has been asked before. This is okay - duplicates are a good thing.

Comment: And welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn about how we operate here and you also visit the [help] for more information. Happy gaming!